# Understanding gradient descent learning rate for curve fitting

Tags: polynomials, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

For a piece of code I'm writing, I'm trying to implement gradient descent. I want to use gradient descent to fit data to a formula. To get from a dataset and the formula to a function I can minimize, I use sum of squares. To calculate the derivative of the function, I approximate using dy/dx with a delta of 1e-4.
To keep complexity low, I initially chose gradient descent over Newton or Levenberg-Maquardt. Mainly to get around matrix inversion.

The formula I'd like to fit is $y(x) = a + (b \cdot x) + (c \cdot x^2)$

My example dataset looks like this:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 19.666 | -0.695 |
| 27.777 | -1.050 |
| 38.9027 | -2.075 |

From this dataset I derived the formula:
$$
y(a,b,c) = (-0.695-(a+(19.666 \cdot b)+(19.666^2 \cdot c)))^2 + \\
(-1.050-(a+(27.777 \cdot b)+(27.777^2 \cdot c)))^2 + \\
(-2.075-(a+(38.9027 \cdot b)+(38.9027^2 \cdot c)))^2
$$

I'm starting my gradient descent at $(0,0,0)$.
During iterations, I notice that the chosen learning rate appears to be much to big for parameter c, but more appropriate for parameters a and b. With a learning rate of 1e-5, I'm seeing this output:

| A | B | C | Lsq-y | StepA | Step B | Step C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7.6403 | 246.684 | 8713.64 | 5.89115 | 7.6403e-5 | 0.00246684 | 0.0871364 |
| -7.6403e-5 | -0.00246684 | -0.0871364 | 22245.2 | -0.0045501 | -0.149888 | 5.1814 |

Because the Lsq-y value increases, I stop the execution at this point. I'm diverging.

I'm wondering if gradient descent is the appropriate method, if there are any errors in my approach? I've played around with the learning rate, but haven't found a learning rate that works within say 1 million iterations.

Comment: You can solve your linear system much more efficiently with other methods, but if you insist on gradient descent, then you should scale your features (i.e. $1, x$ and $x^2$ in this case).

Comment: @jake28 Thanks for responding! Which methods or what kinds of methods would you recommend I look into? My practical cases exceed 3 datapoints.
I'm not sure what you mean by scaling the features, can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: My knowledge about numerical methods is very limited but if you just want a fit for your parameters, can't you just use a standard implementation of the pseudo-inverse in MATLAB (or whatever language you are using)? (see [Polynomial Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression) )  I will try to provide an answer if I find more time, but in the meantime I suggest a google search with "feature scaling gradient descent" or something similar!

Comment: If you want to see why gradient descent performs poorly in your case, try to minimize the function $f(x,y)=x^2+1000 y^2$ .

Comment: @jake28 I see what you mean. Feature scaling appears to be the solution, although it puzzles me how to choose the scale when you don't know the function or anything about the solution in advance. I'll have a look into that, aswell as Polynomial Regression. Thanks for your help!

(I don't think I can reward you with the bounty, because your comments are not seen as an official answer).

Comment: One possibility would be to subtract the mean and divide by the variance of each feature, this doesn't really require a choice. In this way, you can guarantee that each of your parameters influences your cost function roughly equally. (No problem, maybe someone else finds time to give a more detailed argument - including some pictures!)

Comment: Offsetting/Scaling my X-values yields different values for a/b/c. I guess I should apply some kind of transformation in order to get the a/b/c for the unscaled formula?

Comment: Yes. But if you don't do this for study purposes, then you can just compute the pseudo-inverse (using some numerical library) of your design matrix $X$ (whose rows consist of $1,x,x^2$) and multiply it with the labels (i.e. the vector $Y^T=(-0.695, -1.050,-2.075)$ ).

For example: In Matlab you can obtain the solution vector $(a,b,c)^T$ by the command $\text{pinv}(X)*Y$.

Comment: Cool, I'll have a look at that. I am coding something in C++. The dataset represents observations of the forward velocity and sink of a glider. In practice a polynomial is used, so I want to fit the best polynomial against about 20 observations.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything about C++ but I'm sure that the pseudo-inverse is implemented in some library and this allows you to get the coefficients of your quadratic polynomial in one line as mentioned above. If you only have the option of matrix inversion, then you can use the formula: $\text{pinv}(X)=(X^T*X)^{-1}*X^{T}$.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least a few possible approaches to this problem.  If you do not require writing all of your own code from the bottom up, a straightforward approach is to use R's polyreg extension.  The line after the word "(Intercept)" shows the coefficients given by the output.

```
#Written in R Version 4.2.1, polyreg version 0.8.0
require(polyreg)
x = c(19.666,27.777,38.9027)   #data points used for fit
y = c(-.695,-1.050,-2.075)
df = data.frame(x,y)

polyFit(df, deg = 2)   #polynomial regression function
getPoly time: 0
lm() time: 0.02
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ ., data = plm.xy)
Coefficients:
(Intercept)     `I(x^1)`     `I(x^2)`  
  -1.207575     0.075505    -0.002514  
#code to plot the points and polynomial fit
xx = seq(0,50,.1)
nf = function(x) -1.207575 + 0.075505*x - 0.002514*x^2
nf
function(x) -1.207575 + 0.075505*x - 0.002514*x^2
plot(x, y)
lines(xx, nf(xx))
```

[image]

If you wish to calculate the polynomial fit with your own code, you can write your own polynomial regression.  One rendition of this approach is given in *Numerical Methods for Engineers* by Chapra and Canale, 7th ed., 2015, page 473.  It is likely also described in other texts on numerical methods.